# inconsistency in 'ng build' vs 'ng build --prod'

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am working on an angular app.

Using

- Angular **5.2.5**
- Angular CLI **1.6.8**

When I executed command

```
ng build
```

I did not get any error, but when I tried production build

```
ng build --prod
```

I got error

> **Property 'someProperty' is private and only accessible within class 'SomeComponent'**.

Reported error was correct, and I fixed it.

The question is **Why dev build did not report this?**.
**Is that a defect in angular-cli** OR am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `--prod` flag activate many optimization flag. One of them is `--aot` for Ahead Of Time compilation. Your component templates are compiled during the build, so TypeScript can detect more issue in your code. You can compile in dev mode but still activate the `--aot` flag if you want to see this error before building for prod.

**From [the official compiler documentation](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)**

> Detect template errors earlier
>
> The AOT compiler detects and reports template binding errors during the build step before users can see them.

Answer (score 38):

`ng build --prod compile with Ahead of time compilation`. To pass the aot compilation you need to pass your property `someProperty` to `public`. [See this issue on angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5621)

Just for reminder the differences between `ng build` and `ng build --prod`:

```
# these are equivalent
ng build --target=production --environment=prod
ng build --prod --env=prod
ng build --prod
# and so are these
ng build --target=development --environment=dev
ng build --dev --e=dev
ng build --dev
ng build
```

And the default option lunch of `--dev` and `--prod` flags:

```
Flag                 --dev    --prod
--aot                false    true
--environment        dev      prod
--output-hashing     media    all
--sourcemaps         true     false
--extract-css        false    true
--named-chunks       true     false
--build-optimizer    false    true with AOT and Angular 5
```

[Documentation ng build](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)

Hope it's help.

Comment: What about Ivy in Angular 9+? It is not using JIT in development, or is it? But I still have this issue of many errors going unnoticed until production build