# I am getting error while production build ng build --prod

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli, angular2-routing

I am getting the following error while production build project is on angular 4.4.4 and error is following.

WARNING in Missing font size at 5113:8. Ignoring.

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/home/mnt/.local/share/Trash/files/front_end/src'
ERROR in Error: Cannot determine the module for class AddWebsiteAndCampaign in /home/mnt/.local/share/Trash/files/front_end/src/app/campaign/campaign-main/campaign-main.component.ts! Add AddWebsiteAndCampaign to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class CompanyEditComponent in /home/mnt/.local/share/Trash/files/front_end/src/app/company/company-edit/company-edit.component.ts! Add CompanyEditComponent to the NgModule to fix it.
    at syntaxError (/home/mnt/.local/share/Trash/files/front_end/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
    at analyzeAndValidateNgModules (/home/mnt/.local/share/Trash/files/front_end/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24306:15)
    at AotCompiler.analyzeModulesAsync (/home/mnt/.local/share/Trash/files/front_end/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23937:46)
    at CodeGenerator.codegen (/home/mnt/.local/share/Trash/files/front_end/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/codegen.js:32:14)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.codeGen (/home/mnt/.local/share/Trash/files/front_end/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:73:30)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then (/home/mnt/.local/share/Trash/files/front_end/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:428:58)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

When I am use `ng build --env=prod` than build is generated but build is not a production build but when I use the command as per angular documentation `ng build --prod` above error happening.
I am using ubuntu 18.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [inconsistency in 'ng build' vs 'ng build --prod'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49065635/inconsistency-in-ng-build-vs-ng-build-prod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you are getting indicates that you have a couple of components (named in the error message) that are not declared in any module.

As the message indicates, you must declare these components in a module.

The reason that a non-prod build works is because it doesn't actually compile everything - some of the code is interpreted instead, and the checking that is done is not as complete.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to debug from here, but you could do:

- check the related @NgModule-s, whether there are some kind of syntax error
- check whether the related components are added to the appeopriate @NgModule (check exports and declarations as well)
- remove the whole node_modules folder, and reinstall them via npm install
- check main.ts as well and all referenced file